Why does my USB HDD detect as /dev/sdr?
I have a Synology RT2600ac router with an OWC Mercury Elite Pro (USB, eSATA, FW800) external HDD. The drive is detected as /dev/sdr where any ol' USB flash drive is detected as /dev/sda or sdb. Why sdr and not sda? Is this a RAID device convention?
I say RAID because the external enclosure uses a JMicron JMS5662 chip which supports hardware RAID0 & RAID1 for two disks, even though this enclosure only supports one drive. A rare instance of over-engineering?
This is all part of a bigger quest to figure out why this drive keeps getting a new GUID every time it's reconnected or the router is rebooted, and therefore disregards any folder shares created.
To be clear, the folder shares still exist in /usr/syno/etc/share_rights.map but instead of a stable GUID, the drive gets a value of RANDOM__13-digit-hex-GUID in /usr/syno/etc/usbno_guid.map and the folder shares in share_rights.map map to the previously issued RANDOM__13-digit-hex-GUID and partition number.
Unfortunately, lsusb is not an available command. Below is the output from dmesg -T | grep usb
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:08 2024] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:08 2024] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:08 2024] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:19 2024] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:19 2024] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:19 2024] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] scsi host2: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:45 2024] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[Thu Apr 11 02:36:46 2024] Adding 608248k swap on /volumeUSB3/usbshare3-2/@sharebin/@tmp/swapfile.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:608248k

usb 2-1 is the OWC ext drive
usb 3-1 is a USB flash drive
Anyone have any guesses about this? (I've contacted Synology support and am awaiting tier 2 support.)
In case it comes up:
Synology RT2600ac is running BusyBox v1.16.1
It's up-to-date with the latest software - SRM 1.3.1-9346 Update 9
EDIT: Adding more dmesg output
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: xHCI Host Controller
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.0.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: hcc params 0x0228f065 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x00010010
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: irq 185, io mem 0x10000000
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 3-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] hub 4-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[Thu Apr 11 02:34:20 2024] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage


Is there any chance looking at the last sector of the volume, as suggested in the following post could reveal a clue? https://askubuntu.com/questions/249158/ext4-filesystem-wrongly-detected-as-jmicron-raid-member sudo dd if=/dev/mapper/foo-root bs=512 count=1 skip=$((`sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/mapper/foo-root` - 1)) | xxd

On an embedded device it could also simply be a kernel patch, so something specific to your device firmware. Is there dmesg of the detection process (w/o grep)? Drive works normally on other systems?

@frostschutz, I added what seemed relevant to the original question. Any keywords you recommend I look for?

It seems Synology specific, I'm not too familiar with it, sorry.

I will have the device in hand later this week and will test connecting to Linux (Raspberry Pi) to see if it's the enclosure or the Synology.
